# group by monthname in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table which looks like:

```
id    |   Item  | Quantity | Amount | created
________________________________________________
1     | Monitor | 10       | 5000   | 2013-01-11
2     | Keyboard| 10       | 200    | 2013-02-19
3     | Monitor | 10       | 5000   | 2013-02-13
3     | Keybard | 10       | 200    | 2013-04-19
```

when I pass the query:

```
SELECT monthname( created ) AS
MONTH , sum( quantity ) AS qty
FROM `sales`
WHERE year( created ) = '2013'
GROUP BY monthname( created )
ORDER BY monthname( created ) DESC
```

It gives the result:

```
month      |  qty    
______________________
January    | 10
February   | 20
April      | 10
```

But what I was trying to retrieve is:

```
month      |  qty    
______________________
January    | 10
February   | 20
March      | 0
April      | 10
```

- Since I have no sales no march the result must return march sales with quantity 0.
- I am using Codeigniter in my application so if we can't solve it through sql then may be you can show me the way to solve it through Codeigniter.

  ```
  $this->db->select('monthname(created) as month, sum(quantity) as qty');
  $this->db->from('sales');
  $this->db->where('year(created) = 2013');
  $this->db->group_by('monthname(created)');
  $this->db->order_by('monthname(created)');
  $this->data['sales'] = $this->db->get()-result();
  ```

In the view:

```
$data = array();

foreach($sales as $sale) {
  $data[] = $sale->qty;
}
```

Output of `$data`:

```
10, 20, 10 in array;
```

what I need is

```
10, 20, 0, 10 array
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916322/mysql-to-select-month-wise-record-even-if-data-not-exist

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516688/sql-to-select-one-record-for-every-month-with-a-sum-of-that-months-records

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to have a month table which looks as follows

```
id | Month
---------------------
 1 | January
 2 | February
 3 | March
 4 | April
 5 | May
 6 | June
 7 | July
 8 | August
 9 | September
10 | October
11 | November
12 | December
```

name this table as **months**

and you can use the query as below

```
SELECT
    months.`month`,
    Sum(sales.quantity)
FROM
    sales
RIGHT OUTER JOIN months ON months.`month` = monthname(sales.created)
GROUP BY
    months.`month`
ORDER BY
    months.id
```

This should work fine!

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02808/5) that would help you